# Is there a way to determine whether a file is in YAML or JSON format?

Tags: python, json, yaml

I have a Python test script that requires a configuration file.  The configuration file is expected to be in JSON format.

But some of the users of my test script dislike the JSON format because it's unreadable.

So I changed my test script so that it expects the configuration file in YAML format, then converts the YAML file to a JSON file.

I would prefer that the function that loads the configuration file to handle both JSON and YAML.  Is there a method in either the yaml or json module that can give me a Boolean response if the configuration file is JSON or YAML?

My workaround right now is to use two try/except clauses:

```
import os
import json
import yaml

# This is the configuration file - my script gets it from argparser but in
# this example, let's just say it is some file that I don't know what the format
# is
config_file = "some_config_file"

in_fh = open(config_file, "r")

config_dict = dict()
valid_json = True
valid_yaml = True

try:
    config_dict = json.load(in_fh)
except:
    print "Error trying to load the config file in JSON format"
    valid_json = False

try:
    config_dict = yaml.load(in_fh)
except:
    print "Error trying to load the config file in YAML format"
    valid_yaml = False

in_fh.close()

if not valid_yaml and not valid_json:
    print "The config file is neither JSON or YAML"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Now, there is a Python module I found on the Internet called isityaml that can be used to test for YAML.  But I'd prefer not to install another package because I have to install this on several test hosts.

Does the json and yaml module have a method that gives me back a Boolean that tests for their respective formats?

```
config_file = "sample_config_file"

# I would like some method like this
if json.is_json(in_fh):
    config_dict = json.load(in_fh)
```

Comment: Isn't YAML a superset of JSON? You should be able to just load the file as YAML unconditionally. (I'm not sure whether it's an exact superset - I think previous versions weren't.)

Comment: Couldn't you just require that YAML files have one extension and JSON files have a different one?

Comment: user2357112, there are two problems. 

1) Some users might name their configuration file without a .yml or .json suffix so I can't go by the suffix in their configuration file

2) Just because a file has a .yml suffix doesn't necessarily mean that the file is in the YAML format.

Comment: user2357112, I tested loading a json file using yaml.load and loading a yaml file using json.load and both asserted (this was outside a try/except block)

Comment: **do not use** PyYAML's `load()`, on uncontrolled data, it is *unsafe* (i.e. you can get your disc wiped).

Comment: @user2357112 That only applies to YAML 1.2, and the OP is using PyYAML (deducted from the use of `import yaml`) and that doesn't support YAML 1.2, only 1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the `json` and `yaml` modules' documentation, it looks like they don't offer any appropriate modules. However, a common Python idiom is [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/25507) ("easier to ask forgiveness than permission"); in other words, go ahead and try to do the operation, and deal with exceptions if they arise.

```
def load_config(config_file):
    with open(config_file, "r") as in_fh:
        # Read the file into memory as a string so that we can try
        # parsing it twice without seeking back to the beginning and
        # re-reading.
        config = in_fh.read()

    config_dict = dict()
    valid_json = True
    valid_yaml = True

    try:
        config_dict = json.loads(config)
    except:
        print "Error trying to load the config file in JSON format"
        valid_json = False

    try:
        config_dict = yaml.safe_load(config)
    except:
        print "Error trying to load the config file in YAML format"
        valid_yaml = False
```

You could make your own `is_json` or `is_yaml` function if you wanted.  This would involve processing the configuration twice, but that may be okay for your purposes.

```
def try_as(loader, s, on_error):
    try:
        loader(s)
        return True
    except on_error:
        return False

def is_json(s):
    return try_as(json.loads, s, ValueError)

def is_yaml(s):
    return try_as(yaml.safe_load, s, yaml.scanner.ScannerError)
```

Finally, as @user2357112 alluded to, ["every JSON file is also a valid YAML file"](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759572) (as of YAML 1.2), so you should be able to unconditionally process everything as YAML (assuming you have a YAML 1.2-compatible parser; Python's default `yaml` module isn't).

Comment: Your last statement doesn't really apply, as the OPs `import yaml` refers to PyYAML which only supports the older YAML 1.1 specification.

Comment: Doing `try` and `except` without specifying the exceptions is bad practice.  The exception to catch in the case of JSON is **`ValueError**.  The yaml module doesn't even raise exceptions.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError is a subclass of UnicodeError which itself is a subclass of ValueError.  When your script catches Ctrl-C (ExceptionError), for example, you wouldn't want the `except` block in your load_config() function to handle that.

Comment: I tried `with open("/etc/passwd") as f: d = yaml.load_safe(f)` and no exception was triggered.  Anyway, I would use yaml.scanner.ScannerError as an exception to catch.

Comment: @RicardoBranco - /etc/passwd is parsed as a single YAML string. `yaml.safe_load('a: b: c')` will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoBranco.  I will specify the exceptions in the except clause.

Answer (score 8):

From your

```
import yaml
```

I conclude that you use the old PyYAML. That package only supports YAML 1.1 (from 2005) and the format specified there is not a full superset of JSON. With the YAML 1.2 (released 2009), the YAML format became a superset of JSON.

The package [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) supports YAML 1.2. You can install it in your python virtual enviroment with `pip install ruamel.yaml`. And by replacing PyYAML by `ruamel.yaml` (and not adding a package), you can just do:

```
import os
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

config_file = "some_config_file"

yaml = YAML()
with open(config_file, "r") as in_fh:
    config_dict = yaml.load(in_fh)
```

and load the file into `config_dict`, not caring about whether the input is YAML or JSON and no need for having a test for either format.

Answer (score 0):

After years I met the same trouble. I fully agree with EAFP, but still I'm trying find the best detection if the configuration file is in JSON format or YAML.
In code I have methods which inform user **where** he did issue in json-file and where in YAML. try/except did not handle this as I really want, and my eyes are bleeding when I see those nested blocks.

This is not perfect, still has minor issues, but for me, the basic concept fits my needs. I'd say "good enough".

My solution is: find all possible standalone commas in configuration file. If config file contains standalone commas (separators in json) we have json-file, if we do not find any commas, it's yaml.
In my yaml-file I use commas only in comments (between " ") and in lists (between [ ]).
Maybe someone will find it usefull.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

commas = re.compile(r',(?=(?![\"]*[\s\w\?\.\"\!\-\_]*,))(?=(?![^\[]*\]))')
"""
Find all commas which are standalone 
 - not between quotes - comments, answers
 - not between brackets - lists
"""
file_path = Path("example_file.cfg")
signs = commas.findall(file_path.open('r').read())

return "json" if len(signs) > 0 else "yaml"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has been answered already, but here is a way to do it

```
def input_parameters(file):
default_ext = '.json' #set a default extension
file_ext = pathlib.Path(file).suffix
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    if file_ext == default_ext:
        input_file = json.load(f)
    else:
        input_file = yaml.safe_load(f)
return input_file
```