# Determine if a file is either YAML or JSON format

Tags: python, json, file, yaml

I am trying to convert yaml to json.
BUT, Before converting it I need to check if incoming file is yaml or not(this check is mandatory)

I found some piece of code here in [Is there a way to determine whether a file is in YAML or JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338881/is-there-a-way-to-determine-whether-a-file-is-in-yaml-or-json-format) and found below:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

commas = re.compile(r',(?=(?![\"]*[\s\w\?\.\"\!\-\_]*,))(?=(?![^\[]*\]))')
"""
Find all commas which are standalone 
 - not between quotes - comments, answers
 - not between brackets - lists
"""
file_path = Path("example_file.cfg")
signs = commas.findall(file_path.open('r').read())

return "json" if len(signs) > 0 else "yaml"
```

but my input file is not like :

```
example_file.cfg
```

My input would be either `example.yaml` or `example.json`

So I need such comparison without `example_file.cfg`

Thankful if anything found helpful.

Comment: Why don't you just check the file extension of your input?

Comment: If the file extension is not reliable in your case, the accepted answer for the question you linked is what I would do: try to parse it as JSON and YAML, and catch the exceptions.

Comment: If you can use the extension, why try to detect anything? Besides, this regex is overcomplicated. A JSON document can only start with `[` or `{`. All you need to do is check if the first non-space character is `[` or `{`. All you need to do is read the first non-space character from the file. You don't even need to read the entire text

Comment: Every valid JSON file is also a valid YAML 1.2 file [[1\]](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759572), why don't you just load the file as YAML and output it as JSON?

Comment: @Jasmijn Thanks for suggestion but we can not load every file as yaml file. Because we need to give both file options to customer YAML or JSON but if customer is giving YAML file then we need to convert it to json internally and proceed ahead!. Thats why we need one check before proceeding. Check should contain the code to check if incoming file YAML or not if yes then convert it to json first and proceed ahead

Comment: I guess I don't see the problem. `json.dumps(yaml.loads(string_containing_json_or_yaml))` will always produce valid JSON if the string contains valid JSON or YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should work (assuming file can be only json or yaml)

```
import json


def yaml_or_json(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        try:
            json.load(f)
            return 'json'
        except Exception:
            return 'yaml'
```